# Set expiration date for customer passwords

Tags: magento2, customer, admin-panel, password, custom-field

I want to create a new field in Stores -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options for expiration in days for customer password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to added the new fields into `system.xml` file of your custom extension like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
       <section id="customer">
             <group id="password" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

              //ADDED YOUR FIELD HERE             

             </group>
       </section>
    </system>
</config>
```